# Error thrown when call post rest api with big data size

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-web

I have a problem. When I call a post rest api with big data (about 35 megabyte in body) this exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: 
     I/O error on POST request for "x": Software caused connection abort: recv failed; 
     nested exception is java.net.SocketException: 
     Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

I am using wildfly web server and set maxPostSize=250961630, but it is not working.

Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved. In Spring boot,you must define multipartConfigElement bean and set value on setMaxFileSize and setMaxRequestSize properties.The code is:

```
@Bean
public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement()
{
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    factory.setMaxFileSize("1000MB");
    factory.setMaxRequestSize("1000MB");
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
}
```